Where can I find pivoting hinges for a pivot transom window?
We are rebuilding some above-door wood center pivot transom windows, but I can't for the life of me find a hinge that will stay where the window is rotated to.
The window looks like this:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/whiteknuckled/5480519681/
https://www.flickr.com/photos/whiteknuckled/5481119904/in/photostream/
https://s42814.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/10_indiana_queen_anne.jpg.webp
When open I would like them to stay at a 75-90 degree angle. I keep reading about pivoting friction hinges, but I can't find the right shape that will attach properly to both the casement and the sash.
I've tried the following:
Friction Lid Stays (both curved and straight), chains, spring lid supports, lid hinges, magnets.
Got any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

You have center pivot transoms.
You cannot use pivot friction hinges in this application without doing a lot of work. To install these types of hinges you must remove the stops on both the sash and frame and rabbet out space to accommodate the hinge.
A cord attached to a block and tackle placed above the transom is your easiest solution. You may need to attach a weight on the top of the sash opposite the block and tackle to force the sash to tilt when you open it.
